# Sign in with google account not working

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm trying to include 'Sign in Google account' feature in one of our application. I'm following this documentation - https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/

I copied the whole HTML code & just replace that CLIENT ID with mine one.

My Authorized JavaScript origins is : http://localhost:80
and Authorized redirect URI is : http://localhost/testing/test.php

My testing file path where i've copied all HTML code(given by google doc)  is "http://localhost/testing/esp.php"

So, when i'm executing 'esp.php' file I'm getting the google sign in button. On click of that button, I'm getting the popup for login with gmail id. But, after login that popup just vanish & I'm not getting any further info.

In my browser's console also i'm not getting any thing. I belive i should get outout of following javasctip code.

```
console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
console.log("Name: " + profile.getName());
console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
```

Any idea, where I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've fixed this. The mistake which I was making is - I was creating a simple API key rather than OAuth API KEY.

Then in at Authorized JavaScript origins place I was giving "http://localhost:80". It should be the host name like "http://localhost".

Again in place of 'Authorized redirect URIs' section it should be 'http://localhost/oauth2callback'.

That's it & it'll do the rest of the magic... ;)